# Android Studio Mac new project errors after freshly created project

Tags: android, xml, macos, intellij-idea

When I create  a new project on android studio, I get the error. `"URI is not registered"` on my  `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` . I go to my event log, click configure, and the error goes away, yet I get errors in the `"android:icon, label and theme"` values under application along with the `"android:name and label"` attributes under activity in the AndroidManifest.xml.

Also, when trying to open my activity_main.xml layout files, I get the error

```
10:23:12 AM IllegalStateException: @NotNull method com/android/tools/idea/rendering/ManifestInfo.getActivityThemes must not return null
```

It works on the PC, but I am definitely missing something on the Mac. Thanks for all of the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to version 3.0 Canary build on Mac. Fixes all problems.